# Why is accesing services by classname good?

Tags: symfony, service

I've always worked in Symfony 2.2 and 2.8
Now glancing at the [blog of the version 3.3](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-optional-class-for-named-services) and I can't overcome the new feature of getting services by (fully qualified) class name:

```
// before Symfony 3.3
$this->get('app.manager.user')->save($user);

// Symfony 3.3
$this->get(UserManager::class)->save($user);
```

Before Symfony 3.3 the service container was a factory with the knowledge of how to instantiate the service class, with the great benefit of a factory: You can swith the old class to any other class, and as long as they both let's say implement the same interface, maybe you don't even have to touch anything else in your code. But if you ask for a service by class name, you have to refactor your whole code, and change the class name in every occurrence of the service. Either when directly accessing by $container->get() or by using typehint and autowire.

Considering these the old way service aliasing seem much more practical or am I just missing something? I know you still can use it the old way, I'm just wondering in what cases could one benefit from preferring this new method instead the classic one.

Comment: It's mainly to make it a bit easier to make service definitions.  No need to think of and maintain a name if the class name is already available.

Answer (score 1):

One of the main points about the new style of service naming it to avoid asking for services by name directly from the container. By typehinting them all (and having them instead created by the framework), then any service that is not being used at all (and is private, so not `get`-able), can be removed. Anything that is hinted via the container and does not exist will immediately fail on the container building step as well - it would not be possible to rename a service and forget to also change all the other uses of it.

With so much being injected into the controllers (or a controller action) as well, unit testing the services, and even controllers is also more controllable - there wouldn't be any other things that are being pulled from the container within a test.

As for the transition, because of the container compilation step, Symfony is very good about being able to say if there is anything wrong, or at least deprecated. It's not hard to mark all the current services as public with just a small Yaml snippet at the top of each services.yml file (or anywhere else they are defined).

It will be a while until most of the 3rd party bundles and other supporting libraries will be fully 4.0 compatible, but it was also the case for the breaking changes between 2.8 & 3.0. This is a large part of the reason why 2.8 & now 3.4 are long-term-supported versions - with [3.4 supported to November 2021](https://symfony.com/roadmap?version=3.4#checker), giving plenty of time to upgrade away from the deprecations and update the 3rd party bundles.